# Web scrawling - scrape the keywords and make a list using Python

Tags: python, jupyter

I am struggling to find out the ways to scrape the keywords from the website and make a visualized list.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1677720/keywords?ref_=tttg_ql_4

This is an URL of a website I will use, and I have to scrawl out only 10 or 20 keywords from the site, and make a list to visualize the data.

I have installed Python 3, requests, bs4, lxml, and other programs for jupyter notebook, and found a code like this. I think I may use this code reforming the URL and other settings, but I have no idea what to put for the "KEYWORDS" list. I would appreciate every help for my coding

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/22/opinion/ted-cruz-a-pressure-point-for-north-korea.html?action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=opinion-c-col-left-region&region=opinion-c-col-left-region&WT.nav=opinion-c-col-left-region"
source_code = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup (source_code,"lxml")

title_html = soup.find("meta",{"property":"og:title"})
title = title_html["content"]

date_html = soup.find("meta",{"property":"article:published"})
date = date_html["content"]

reporter_html = soup.find("meta",{"name":"byl"})
reporter =reporter_html["content"]

print(title)
print(date)
print(reporter)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output to make you question clearer.

Comment: Please try to avoid the impression that you want an explanation of how to use some fragment of code you downloaded somewhere.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Echoing/expanding on what @Yunnosch said, the idea behind this site is to help people who are stuck at a very specific point. Your question is a bit broader than that. Perhaps try to read up on the documentation for BeautifulSoup and see how you can modify your code, and if you're encountering a specific error you can try here again.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet produces the required list

1. Send a get request

   ```
   x=requests.get("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1677720/keywords?ref_=tttg_ql_4")
   ```
2. Convert text of the get request in a BS object

   ```
   bs = BeautifulSoup(x.text, 'lxml')
   ```
3. Find all **<td class="soda sodavote">** tags

   ```
   t = bs.find_all('td', attrs={ "class":"soda sodavote"})
   ```
4. Now find all the **<a>** tags because they actually contain the keywords and process them and store them in a list **L**

   ```
   l=[BeautifulSoup(str(k), "lxml").get_text().strip().split(",")[0][1:] for k in [i.find_all("a") for i in t ]]
   ```

To save your time I have given the list *L* below:

```
l = ['capitalism', 'tattooed trash', 'mini skirt', 'slit skirt', 'thin woman', 'girl wearing shorts', 'player', 'short skirt', 'slim girl', 'screenplay adapted by author', 'based on novel', 'virtual reality', 'dystopia', 'battle', 'voice over narration', 'racing', 'love interest', 'key', 'live action and animation', 'inside a movie', 'teenage protagonist', 'drone', 'ceo', 'slender legs', 'pac man', 'three word title', 'future', 'reward', 'outcast', 'based on young adult novel', 'dystopian future', 'reference to back to the future', 'columbus ohio', 'year 2045', 'contest', 'easter egg', 'race against time', 'eccentric millionaire', '80s music', '80s nostalgia', 'reference to 1980s popular culture', 'final battle', 'final showdown', 'reference to peter parker', 'reference to clark kent', 'gun', 'abuse', 'kiss', 'playing a video game', 'fight', 'reference to john hughes', 'avatar', 'male protagonist', 'race', 'teamwork', 'friendship', 'love', '21th century', '2040s', 'woman', 'villain', 'explosion', 'motion capture', 'profanity', 'f word', 'opening action scene', 'epic game', 'brawl', 'fistfight', 'nightclub', 'dance', 'dancing', 'shootout', 'gunfight', 'sword', 'sword fight', 'ninja', 'ninja sword', 'samurai', 'samurai sword', 'katana sword', 'machine gun', 'pistol', 'laser gun', 'epic', 'epic battle', 'showdown', 'disarming someone', 'fighting', 'combat', 'hand to hand combat', 'duel', 'motorcycle', 'motorcycle chase', 'car chase', 'chase', 'teenager fighting adult', 'teenage hero', 'villain arrested', 'hero', 'martial arts', 'cameo', 'fictional war', 'redhead', 'violence', 'boy', 'girl', 'technology', 'based on a book', 'based on a novel', 'gear', 'equipment', 'skyscraper', 'high rise', 'container', 'apartment', 'billboard', 'advertisement', 'advertising', 'commercial', 'antenna', 'flying car', 'wreck', 'backpack', 'knapsack', 'glasses', 'eyeglasses', 'jeans', 'trash', 'trash heap', 'car', 'aeroplane', 'travel', 'unhappy with oneself', 'inferiority complex', 'space', 'computer', 'voice', 'female computer voice', 'nerd', 'geek', 'computer monitor', 'capitalist', 'businessman', 'suit and tie', 'employee', 'mission', 'american flag', 'flag of hate', 'reference to war and peace', 'product placement', 'thin girl', 'tattoo', 'tattooed arm', 'white trash', 'aunt', 'nephew', 'aunt nephew conflict', 'miniskirt', 'female stockinged leg', 'female stockinged legs', 'prize', 'prize money', 'body suit', 'corporate', 'corporation', 'management', 'tabbouleh salad', 'orb', 'riddle', 'newspaper', 'newspaper clip', 'news clipping', 'fan', 'adulation', 'magazine clipping', 'revelation', 'date', '80s', '80s culture', 'disco', 'discotheque', 'thin and attractive', 'thin attractive girl', 'reality', 'greed', 'turtleneck', 'bangs', 'thin attractive woman', 'slim and attractive', 'slender attractive woman', 'shoulder length hair', 'ginger', 'shorts', 'birth mark', 'cute girl', 'corporate spying', 'corporate dystopia', 'blood stream', 'river of blood', 'typewriter', 'pop culture', 'pop culture reference', 'jean shorts', 'denim shorts', 'thin legs', 'pretty legs', 'eye popping out', 'rain', 'technology used for evil', 'face tattoo', 'dumpster', 'chinese character', 'corporate enslavement', 'enslavement', 'corporate sell out', 'unreal', 'artificial', 'strap', 'wired', 'sticky note', 'sticky note with password on it', 'japanese', 'near future', 'high tech', 'fight the system', 'social commentary', 'megacorporation', 'british actor playing american character', 'cyberpunk', 'macguffin', 'eccentric', 'millionaire', 'british actress playing american character', 'founder', 'inventor', 'revenge', 'resistance', 'resistance fighter', 'battlefield', 'van', 'african american', 'greenhouse', 'interracial friendship', '11 year old', 'mixed martial arts', '18 year old', 'punched in the face', 'woman fights a man', 'little boy', 'car truck chase', 'foot chase', 'little girl', 'car motorcycle chase', 'rival', 'rivalry', 'teenager', 'exploding body', 'exploding car', 'exploding trailer', 'exploding building', 'no opening credits', 'car race', 'car crash', 'car accident', 'overturning car', 'car rollover', 'train', 'train derailment', 'el train', 'wrecking ball', 'teenage boy', 'teenage girl', 'grenade launcher', 'eavesdropping', 'unlikely hero', 'coming of age', 'orphan', 'aunt nephew relationship', 'death of aunt', 'cell phone', 'part computer animation', 'surrealism', 'casino', 'planet', 'black comedy', 'wisecrack humor', 'security guard', 'magical object', 'magic spell', 'portal', 'shape shifting', 'teleportation', 'hologram', 'force field', 'shield', 'surveillance', 'security camera', 'video footage', 'curator', 'museum', 'journal', 'library', 'quest', 'hunt', 'surveillance footage', 'golden egg', 'evil businessman', 'corrupt businessman', 'corporate corruption', 'evil corporation', 'corporate crime', 'police', 'police car', 'police officer', 'handcuffs', 'arrest', 'lawyer', 'mercenary', 'henchwoman', 'army', 'destruction', 'chaos', 'obscene finger gesture', 'raised middle finger', 'ambush', 'aerial shot', 'knocked out', 'kidnapping', 'hostage', 'held at gunpoint', 'rescue', 'escape', 'deception', 'betrayal', 'double cross', 'blood', 'blood on camera lens', 'murder', 'death', 'lens flare', 'mercilessness', 'boardroom', 'empire state building manhattan new york city', 'new york city', 'central park manhattan new york city', 'racetrack', 'driving in reverse', 'reference to batman', 'reference to lex luthor', 'castle', 'reference to superman', 'reference to duran duran', 'reference to michael jackson', 'electrocution', 'reference to star trek', 'reference to the millenium falcon', 'reference to star wars', 'reference to king kong', 'reference to godzilla', 'reference to the iron giant', 'reference to halo', 'reference to stephen king', 'reference to bill and ted', 'dinosaur', 'reference to spiderman', 'reference to james bond', 'levitation', 'mecha', 'giant robot', 'slave labor', 'videotape', 'robot', 'slum', 'consumerism', 'slow motion scene', 'dual wield', 'stylized violence', 'hotel', 'elevator', 'bathtub', 'photograph', 'workshop', 'zombie', 'maze', 'axe', 'mountain', 'snow', 'volcano', 'self sacrifice', 'mercy killing', 'sabotage', 'power outage', 'mechanic', 'prologue', 'newspaper clipping', 'trailer', 'trailer home', 'trailer park', 'junkyard', 'disguise', 'nostalgia', 'treadmill', 'headset', 'falling through ice', 'montage', 'virtuality', 'reference to aliens', 'giant', 'competition', 'reference to alien', 'reference to mortal kombat', 'challenge', 'contract', 'hall of records', 'hunter', 'dynamite', 'bomb', 'hand grenade', 'plunger detonator', 'blockbuster', "rubik's cube", 'manhattan new york city', 'unrequited love', 'redemption', 'tragic past', 'dark past', 'female fighter', 'warrior', 'heroism', 'bravery', 'courage', 'tough girl', 'female warrior', 'hallucination', 'computer hacker', 'computer cracker', 'loss of aunt', 'desperation', 'cyberspace', 'tracking device', 'fire breathing', 'fire', 'rebel', 'rebellion', 'bombardment', 'coin flip', 'coin', 'credits as currency', 'power', 'laser', 'silencer', 'clue', 'uniformed police officer', 'man wears a suit and tie', 'man wears eyeglasses', 'woman wears a miniskirt', 'woman wears a short skirt', 'based on book', 'surprise ending', 'number in title']
```